# DB user requires SUPER privilege to create attributes (SQLSTATE[42000])

Tags: attributes, mysql, error, ee-1.13.1.0

When I try to create an attribute for this one EE 1.13.1.0 installation, it gives me the following error. `myuser` is the MySQL user for the Magento installation with table, `mytable`.

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1227 Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation
```

This user has the following GRANTS just like any other MySQL users for different development instances I have.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mytable`.* TO 'myuser'@'192.%'
```

I can create products and anything else, but I just can't create attributes. If I set `Super_priv` to `Y` then `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`, the user can perform attribute creation, but none of the other users I have set up for different instances require `Super_priv` to be `Y`.

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the way that EE 1.13+ are handling reindexing jobs. The attribute index is being kicked off by a MySQL Trigger - this function creation/execution requires SUPER privilege to execute.

[image]

Here is an example of the AFTER INSERT trigger fired on `catalog_eav_attribute`

```
BEGIN
CASE (NEW.is_searchable = 1) OR (NEW.is_visible_in_advanced_search = 1) OR (NEW.is_filterable > 0) OR (NEW.is_filterable_in_search = 1) OR (NEW.used_for_sort_by = 1) OR (NEW.is_used_for_promo_rules = 1) OR (NEW.used_in_product_listing = 1) WHEN TRUE THEN BEGIN UPDATE `enterprise_mview_metadata` AS `mm`
 INNER JOIN `enterprise_mview_metadata_event` AS `me` ON mm.metadata_id = me.metadata_id
SET `mm`.`status` = 2
WHERE (mview_event_id = '5'); END; ELSE BEGIN END; END CASE;
END
```

Potential workarounds require some guessing on my part:

- drop triggers and recreate them with the current user (perhaps you imported as root?)
- delete the eav triggers altogether and rely on manual reindexing
- obviously you could just grant SUPER to the MySQL user